# Declaring a "default deny" for SpringBoot 3 @MethodSecurity (via SecurityFilterChain?)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have `@PreAuthorize()` for each method and would like to set a "default deny" for all methods where I forgot to add an explicit annotation.

With SpringBoot 2.x I was able to declare a `SecurityFilterChain` that permits some infrastructure endpoints like `/actuator` and `/swagger-ui` and then denies the rest. The annotations from `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` were processed earlier so that an explicit PERMIT there would let the request through.
Now afte migrating to SpringBoot 3.x with `@EnableMethodSecurity` (without "global") and `authorizeHttpRequests` (with "http") that does not work anymore.
It seems that either the order of the filters or the decision strategy has somehow changed but I don't find an explanations in the docs how the two ways of securing endpoints work together.

The way it worked for me with SpringBoot 2.7.9 was:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
class OAuth2SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun customOauth2FilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http {
            oauth2ResourceServer {
                jwt { jwtAuthenticationConverter = CustomBearerJwtAuthenticationConverter() }
            }
            oauth2Login {}
csrf { disable() }

            authorizeRequests {
              // Kubernetes
              authorize("/readiness", permitAll)
              authorize("/liveness", permitAll)
              ...
              // everything else needs at least a valid login, roles are checked at method level
              authorize(anyRequest, authenticated)
            }
        }
        return http.build()
    }
 }
```

REST Controllers looked like this:

```java
@RestController
@DenyAll // default
class CustomerFragmentController(

    @GetMapping("/api/foo")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc')")
    fun foo(): Foo { ... }

    @GetMapping("/api/bar")  // should be denied by @DenyAll
    fun bar(): Bar { ... }
}
```

Comment: You said "was", has this order changed? Anyway, as I used authenticated as last statement in `SecurityFilterChain` that probably means that the request always passed through this filter. So the change in behaviour seems only to be in @EnableMethodSecurity which stops after the @DenyAll and does not check if there is a "more-specific" @PreAuthorize, right?

Comment: Using the debugger I found my old application to use the `AffirmativeBased` implementation of an `AccessDecisionManager`. In https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html it says "unanimous-based is the default behavior with @EnableMethodSecurity". So I apparently have to read how to add a custom authorization manager if I want the old behaviour back.

Comment: Good for you, you found the reason. Good for me, I learned something.

Comment: Although I found the reason, I'm still not able to configure some kind of AffirmativeBased behaviour with `@EnableMethodSecurity`.
Maybe this combination of the results of the JSR205 @DenyAll and Spring @PreAuthorize votes is what needs a "global" DecisionManager.